# Exponential upper bound for $\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \alpha^k \beta^{\frac{1}{N-k}}$

Tags: bounds

I will be too happy help me find the exact value or a very tight exponential upper bound for:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \alpha^k \beta^{\frac{1}{N-k}}$$
where $0 \leq \alpha < 1$, $\beta= \exp(-N^2\zeta)$ and $\zeta$ is a positive small value.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Exponential in what quantity? Note that $$\alpha \beta  \frac{1-\alpha^{N-1}}{1-\alpha} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \alpha^k \beta^{\frac{1}{N-k}} \leq \alpha \beta^{\frac{1}{N-1}}  \frac{1-\alpha^{N-1}}{1-\alpha}.$$

Comment: @cardinal, Thanks a lot for your answer, your derived upper bound coincides with my result, but I think it is not tight at all? Do you have any suggestion to find a tighter bound?

Comment: You've changed the question and added information since I posted that, including making $\beta$ a function of $N$ instead of a constant with respect to $N$. I'll give it some more thought.